# IntelliJ IDEA can't show some code characters on a regular basis

Tags: intellij-idea

As you can see, in my IntelliJ IDEA, some code characters were hidden on the editor. After restarting the IDE, the problem will be solved occasionally. Why did it happen?

Issue:

[image: screenshot of code]

IDE and OS:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2
- Build #IU-171.4249.39, built on April 25, 2017
- JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b16 x86_64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Mac OS X 10.13.3

Note:

I've tried to switch IDE boot JDK to oracleJDK, it seems to solve the problem mentioned above, but some of the features of the IDE have failed :(

Comment: Does it work if use Oracle JDK to run IDE under (see [Switching the IDE boot JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.1/switching-boot-jdk.html#d750458e20) or [Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879)? Also try switching different antialiasing methods in editor in File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance. Does it change anything?

Comment: Did this problem happen just once, or does it happen on a regular basis? If latter, you should report it to the IntelliJ IDEA issue tracker.

Comment: @yole on a regular basis

Comment: Hi Shawock, please note that [comments are temporary and could be deleted anytime](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have additional information to provide, such as *"on a regular basis"*, please update your question by clicking on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/204869) for details. Thank you.

Comment: From your screenshot, it seems that only the letters `i`, `l` and `v` of a particular font would be hidden.